# rectangle with one curved side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I would like to create a filled rectangle with one curved side such as 
one shown in the picture below:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,thick] (0,-3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3) edge [bend left] (1,-3);
\draw[red,thick,fill] (1,-3)  edge [bend right] ( 0, -3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am not able to fill it correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `tape` shape from `shapes` tikz` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[tape, draw]{ABCD};
\node[tape, draw, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=2mm,   %% tape bend bottom=none
            tape bend bottom=out and in,fill=red,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=3cm] at (2.5, 0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to draw them deliberately, here you go:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,thick,fill=olive!40] (0,-3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3) 
                        to [out=220,in=30]  ( 0, -3) --cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,thick,fill=olive] (0,-3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3)
                        to [out=220,in=-40]  (1,-3) 
                        to [out=140,in=30] ( 0, -3) --cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a try with MetaPost, but I guess it can easily be adapted to *tikz* using the [*hobby*](http://tug.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/hobby_doc.pdf) package: it takes advantage of MetaPost's powerful path specifications and constructions (using John Hobby's algorithm) that the *hobby* package allows to import to *tikz*. It suffices to specify adequate directions (as angles) at the two basis points of the rectangle.

To be processed with whatever engine (LaTeX, pdfLaTeX…) in *shell-escape* mode.

**EDIT** I've added a *tikz* version, using thus the *hobby* package, at the end of this post, producing the same picture. The code is certainly a bit rudimentary since I don't know much of *tikz* yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost*}
  u = 1cm; % scale
  myangle = 30; % "curving" parameter, in degrees
  z = (2u, 3u); 
  path rect; rect = origin{dir myangle} .. (x, 0){dir myangle} -- z -- (0, y) -- cycle;
  fill rect withcolor red; draw rect withcolor blue;
\end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[blue, fill=red, use Hobby shortcut] ([out angle = 30, in angle = -150]0,0)  .. (2,0) 
  -- (2,3) -- (0,3) -- cycle ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by piecing together two arcs with a rectangle:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\x{34.0} % Angle parameter
\def\y{1.79} % Radius parameter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red,thick] (0,-3) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,-3) -- cycle; 
\filldraw[red] (3,-2.99) arc (-90+\x:-90-\x:\y);
\filldraw[white] (0,-3.01) arc (90+\x:90-\x:\y/2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: shape]

When overlaid with the original outline (in blue):

[image: orignal]