# Show that drawing is cutoff with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-path

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (-1,-2) -- (-1,0);
\draw[decorate, decoration = {snake, segment length = .5cm}] (-1.5,-2) -- (-0.5,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to indicate that my drawing has been cutoff at a certain point by wavy lines. I don't know the exact term for that style and thus came up with the example above. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe a package, custom arrow tip? Or do I just need to experiment with the pathmorphing?

Ideally the wavy line would be the top part of a white filled box with all other edges also white, so I can just move it over my original drawing.
Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176181/44127):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (0,-2) -- (0,0);

\node[tape, draw, tape bend height=4mm, tape bend top=out and in,  tape bend bottom=none,fill=white,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2cm] at (0,-2) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

end result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: If I got you right, you can use just the `clip` option; clip along the wavy line and then use the last x-coordinate and go straigt up. Then just cycle the rectangle and you get the desired output. Especially for the last picture you can use just the `intersections` library and make an intersection with the wavy line and draw from the intersection with relative coordinates just straight up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given @current_user input I was able to create the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\draw (-1,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (2.5,8) -- cycle;
\draw[black] (-1,-2) -- (-1,14);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\startx}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\endx}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\starty}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\endy}{14}


\begin{scope}
\clip  foreach \x in {\startx,2,...,\endx} { (\x,\starty) to [bend left=25]  (\x+2,\starty) to [bend right=25]  (\x+4,\starty)}  -- (\endx+4,\endy) -- (\startx,\endy) -- (\startx,\starty);
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\draw (-1,-3) -- (6,-3) -- (2.5,8) -- cycle;
\draw[black] (-1,-2) -- (-1,14);
\end{scope}
\draw  foreach \x in {\startx,2,...,\endx} { (\x,\starty) to [bend left=25]  (\x+2,\starty) to [bend right=25]  (\x+4,\starty)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Defining in the clipping area the region I want to keep vs. the region to omit seemed a bit counter intuitive to me, but it works now.